# Worst-Case Graph for Prim's Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, minimum-spanning-tree, prims-algorithm

My Algorithms class is talking about Prim's Algorithm as a method of finding Minimum Spanning Trees of weighted graphs. Our professor asked us to try to think of an example of a graph that Prim's Algorithm takes N^2 time to solve (N = number of Vertices). No one in the class could think of one off the top of their head, so I'm asking you. I'm pretty sure Prim's Algorithm = O(N^2), so this would be the worst-case scenario for the algorithm.

What's a good example of a graph that takes N^2 time for Prim's Algorithm to solve?

Comment: If the graph is complete, there're `O(N^2)` edges, so just reading the graph is `O(N^2)`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, the example is trivial.

If the graph is complete, there're `O(N^2)` edges, so just reading the graph is `O(N^2)`.